# squid3 stop/waiting, is this a bug?

Tags: proxy, squid

After I installed the squid using apt-get, the service was running, but then when I did make changes on the conf file, the service just hang

squid3 stop/waiting

I cannot start it.

Comment: What's the error message when you start it via `service squid3 start`?

Comment: I dont see any error in access.log and cache.log. the service just stuck at squid3 stop/waiting when i start the service

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. It has something to do the config file, squid.conf

Please make sure when you enable the

```
http_access allow localnet
```

There is a network set on your acl

```
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 136.198.0.0/16
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
```

If this is empty, squid3 service wont start.

Comment: Thanks! I had some rules in my conf, switching the order did the trick!